# Use ServiceNow instance login for AWS Cognito Apps authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, servicenow

I want to log in to my AWS Cognito app. But on accessing the AWS app, the user should be redirected to the ServiceNow login page, and upon authentication, it should redirect back to the cognito with the token and claims and cognito should return the token to my app for the access.

I have tried the following:

**1. Created an OAuth client in ServiceNow with a Cognito redirect URL**

```
Redirect URL:https://<awsinstance>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse

Auth Scopes: useraccount
```

**2. Created a Cognito user pool**

**3. Configure the ServiceNow Identity Provider (IdP) in Cognito with the following details:**

```
Provider Type: OIDC

ClientId, ClientSecret (obtained from ServiceNow OAuth Client)

Authorized Scopes: openid useraccount

Attribute request method: POST

Authorization endpoint: https://<my_instance_id>.service-now.com/oauth_auth.do

Token endpoint: https://<my_instance_id>.service-now.com/oauth_token.do
```

I couldn't find the Issuer_URL and UserInfo endpoint so put the servicenow instance url for both.

**4. Added the following Claim mappings:**

```
username -> sub

email -> email

name -> name
```

**5. Configure the Cognito App Client to use the ServiceNow IDP**

After doing all this when I try to access the Cognito App Client Hosted UI, it goes to the ServiceNow and call the redirect url with the error response that username+attribute+mapping+required. And in header response it returns the code and state.

How can I get the user claims and token from it? Are the above steps correct for what I am trying to acheive?